# Flatten an object of child arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have Object which look like

```
list:{
    dynamicPerson: [
        0: {
            name:"Andrew", 
            company:"xCompany"
        }, 
        1: {
            name:"Joseph",
            company:"zCompany"
        }
    ] 
    dynamicPerson2: [
        0: {
            name:"Andrew", 
            company:"xCompany"
        }, 
        1: {
            name:"Joseph", 
            company:"zCompany"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want it like

```
List:[
    0: {
        name:"Andrew",
        company:"xCompany"
    },
    1: {
        name:"Joseph", 
        company:"zCompany"
    },
    2: {
        name:"Andrew", 
        company:"xCompany"
    },
    3: {
        name:"Joseph", 
        company:"zCompany"
    }
]
```

Note DynamicPerson is run time generated key.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: The data structure you want is not a valid array structure, unless the numbers in the front refers to the index of the element instead of an arbitrary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate trought the keys of the object. Map the arrays to an array of array and then flatten it.

```
let flattened = Object.keys(list).map(key => list[key]).flat();
```

I modified your input slightly, because it was not syntactically right.

```js
  let list = {
    dynamicPerson: [
      {
        name: "Andrew",
        company: "xCompany"
      },
      {
        name: "Joseph",
        company: "zCompany"
      }
    ],
    dynamicPerson2: [
      {
        name: "Andrew",
        company: "xCompany"
      },
      {
        name: "Joseph",
        company: "zCompany"
      }
    ]
  };

  let flattened = Object.keys(list)
    .map(key => list[key])
    .flat();

  console.log(flattened);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it yourself by looking for: convert object to array-of-key-value-pairs

But maybe look at the snipped in here: [how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript/)  can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap()`:

```
Object.values(list).flatMap(s => s);
```

An example:

```js
let list ={
    dynamicPerson: [
        {
            name:"Andrew",
            company:"xCompany"
        },
        {
            name:"Joseph",
            company:"zCompany"
        }
    ]
,   dynamicPerson2: [
        {
            name:"Andrew",
            company:"xCompany"
        },
        {
            name:"Joseph",
            company:"zCompany"
        }
    ]
}

const result = Object.values(list).flatMap(s => s);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
let list = {
  dynamicPerson: [{
      name: "Andrew",
      company: "xCompany"
    },
    {
      name: "Joseph",
      company: "zCompany"
    }
  ],
  dynamicPerson2: [{
      name: "Andrew",
      company: "xCompany"
    },
    {
      name: "Joseph",
      company: "zCompany"
    }
  ]
}
let List = Object.values(list).flat();
console.log(List);
```